# To show calendar Events after clicking the prev and next button using simple-calendar.js

Tags: calendar

How to display the Calendar Events after clicking the prev and next button for that selected month only.
Here are the code:
[jquery.simple-calendar.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmh2R.png),[jquery.simple-calendar.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vaip3.png),[jquery.simple-calendar.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5xTM.png),[jquery.simple-calendar.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRwW3.png),[jquery.simple-calendar.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIHgp.png),[jquery.simple-calendar.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHw7q.png),[jquery.simple-calendar.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALzVz.png)

Show calendar Events for the selected Month.